# Plotting lines over histogram

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I want to plot standard deviation and mean on histogram plot like  shown below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
         filename = 'C:\Users\unique.xlsx';
        %removed duplicate entries from the file

           columnB = xlsread(filename,'B:B');



             edges = unique(columnB)



        n_elements =histc(columnB, edges)/numel(columnB);

          bar(edges,n_elements,'BarWidth',4)

           meanB=mean(columnB)   % expectation
           stdB=std(columnB)

          figure(2)
           hold on
            ylim=get(gca,'ylim')
           line([meanB meanB], ylim,'g')
              hold on
           line ([meanB+stdB meanB+stdB NaN meanB-stdB meanB-stdB] , [ylim NaN   ylim],'r')
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
   ??? Error using ==> line
       String argument is an unknown option.

     Error in ==> read at 23
    line([meanB meanB], ylim,'g')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
line([meanB meanB], ylim, 'Color','g');
```

instead of

```
line([meanB meanB], ylim,'g');
```

Comment: Thank you that worked but one problem I want to show the standard deviation with a horizontal line but I get two vertical lines.How can I achieve horizontal line like shown above in figure.